# Anaconda python, PIL and imagingtk

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, anaconda

Although this is a reasonably well [documented](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6) problem, I can't find a solution.

I cannot import PIL and ImageTK.

Minimal example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
image = Image.open('live.ppm')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

This produces the error:

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 181, in paste
    import _imagingtk
ImportError: No module named _imagingtk
```

I have tried:

```
conda install pillow
conda remove PIL
```

But no luck.

Comment: I had the same problem. I had to uninstall the anaconda pillow, and pil, and then pip install Pillow - I didn't need to install Image. Your solution didn't work for me. This is very strange!

Comment: I had to upgrade Pillow to a newest version as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After uninstalling pillow and PIL:

```
pip install image
```

Fixed this issue.

Comment: did you still include the line `from PIL import Image, ImageTk` ?

Comment: Yes you still need that

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for bringing this up.  The ImageTk module is an extra extension that is not part of the default installation of Pillow.

This issue is long-standing: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/150

We (Continuum) will investigate adding this module to our build process.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify the extension of the image, i got the same problem, and when i modified the extension the script worked