# ImportError: cannot import name '_imagingtk'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I am using Anaconda with python 3.4 and I am not able to get all the pillow packages I need I am afraid on Windows 8.1.

I installed pillow via the Anaconda console with:

```
pip install pillow
```

which lead to:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:      3.10.0-py34_0 --> 3.10.1-py34_0
    conda-env:  2.1.3-py34_0  --> 2.1.4-py34_0
    pillow:     2.7.0-py34_0  --> 2.8.1-py34_0
    pip:        6.0.8-py34_0  --> 6.1.1-py34_0
    setuptools: 14.3-py34_0   --> 15.0-py34_0
```

Now, in the spyder IPython console I start with: `import tkinter, from PIL import ImageTk` I have no errors here, but when executing `ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='a.jpg')` I receive an error, telling me: `ImportError: cannot import name '_imagingtk'`

What did I miss?

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue with the Anaconda pillow https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6

Comment: thanks a lot. I will keep an eye on that.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588773/anaconda-python-pil-and-imagingtk

Comment: worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a complete answer, but I have had the same problem and spent a day trying to figure it out...
Here is a small subset of things I tried yesterday to the best of my weak memory...
-Tried upgrating to the latest Python environment using anaconda ([tip](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5089): you can create one using

```
conda update conda 
conda update anaconda
(I think that's it, but may have tried to make sure for key packages explicitly etc.)
```

-Tried using Python 3.3 environment using anaconda ([tip](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5089): you can create one using

```
conda update conda 
conda create -n py33 python=3.3 anaconda
activate py33
```

-Tried using PythonWin instead of anaconda (that one took some time, had to install packets like numpy manually...)

-Tried updating / downgrading / installing/ uninstalling all kinds of different variations of Pillow, PIL, etc....

-Tried using opencv instead of PIL, though did not try to write my own components...

-Tried manually copying Tcl/tk and a few others to the lib directory as suggested by some posts

-Tried using  import tkinter instead of Tkinter, using import Image vs. form PIL import Image (and in general taking Image from PIL, or opencv, or Tkinter) and a lot of other similar changes to the point it fell I was doing silly things

-...

At the end, I googled a few pages about GUIs in python, and now I am using [wx](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html)... I had to run

```
conda install wxpython
```

and that was it. I have to say that after all this, I am presently surprised by how easy it was to make it work, [here is a code example](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/)...

Answer (score -1):

You need  tcl/tk library.

Install them using apt-get

Do `sudo apt-get install tk8.6-dev tcl8.6-dev`

--[Reference](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/322).