# Cannot import name '_imagingtk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I checked a bunch of related questions on here about this topic but almost all of them seem outdated, or the responses are irrelevant to the problem I have.

The lines of code that are relevant are:
`from PIL import Image, ImageTk`, `saveIcon = Image.open('Icons/save.ico')`, and `saveIconP = ImageTk.PhotoImage(saveIcon)`.

The error that the console gives me is `cannot import name _imagingtk`

Also I'm running this on windows 10 with python 3.5 installed, most of the previous responses I've seen have involved Linux/unix sudo grabs for updating packages however I downloaded this last week so I believe most packages are up to date.

Comment: What did you download last week? For python packages, no traditionally downloading of a package is necessary, use [pip to install those packages](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#use-pip-for-installing). Also, in the bunch of related questions, did you find this question outdated or irrelevant: [Anaconda python, PIL and imagingtk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28589089/1248974)? (of course ignoring Anaconda). Pip will also tell you if packages you have installed (if any) are up to date.

Comment: You posted 3 lines of code.  Which one cause the error? The third?  With 3.5 on Win10, I ran the three lines (after creating tk root) first on pillow 3.1.0 and then, after freshly upgrading, 3.3.1.  To repeat download's question, what did you install?  If the obsolete 2.7-only 'PIL', delete and install 'pillow'.  Otherwise try to re-install pillow.  Pillow has PIL.PILLOW_VERSION.